# How to create rows for a table for each index of an array?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, html-table, row, jsx

I'm currently using react.js and JSX to try and create a table.

Given `destinations` is an array of objects, and each object consists of 3 arrays of strings (`hikingTrails`, `campSites`, `slopes`), how can I create a table where each row consists of the strings in each array?

For example,

> - destinations array contains 2 objects.
> - **Object 1** contains 3 arrays: hikingTrails, campSites, slopes.
> - hikingTrails array is empty.
> - campSites array contains 2 strings: Sierra, Yosemite.
> - slopes array is empy.
> - **Object 2** contains 3 arrays: hikingTrails, campSites, slopes.
> - hikingTrails array is empty.
> - campSites array contains 2 strings: XYZ, ABC.
> - slopes array is empty.

I want the table to look like this: 
[image: table1]

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
const allDestinations = destinations.map(destination => (
    <tr key={destination._id}>
        <td>{destination.hikingTrails}</td>
        <td>{destination.campSites}</td>
        <td>{destination.slopes}</td>
    </tr>
));

return ( 
    <Fragment>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tbody>
                    {allDestinations} 
                </tbody>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </Fragment>
);
```

But this results in the following table: 
[image: table2]

Due to campSites being an array, `destination.campSites` returns the whole array ([0]: XYZ, [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3HWh.png): ABC) as one row, and the whole array ([0]: Sierra, [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3HWh.png): Yosemite) as another row, when I want each string on their own row.

How can I create a row for each index of the `destination.campSites` array?

Comment: Your current code is taking each destination as a row, do you want each campsite to be another row or just to be displayed as one? If so, you can just print newlines for each campsite, like `destination.campSites.map(site => {site}<br/>)` or something more organized.

Comment: I want each campsite to be on their own row. I implemented a method similar to your's, but the line break just makes each row have XYZ on top of ABC, but still within one row. Instead, I need XYZ in its own row, and ABC on its own row.